# Carousel slider button does not work in Angular 7

Tags: jquery, html, angular, bootstrap-4

I wrote a simple piece of html code with bootstrap carousel

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="http://10.23.129.132:1313/a.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://10.23.129.132:1313/b.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://10.23.129.132:1313/c.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If I run this as a simple html code, the carousel displays the image normally along with slider function but if I try to use Angular to compile, then only images are displayed. If I click on the slider button, it does not change the image. I inspected if the images are present, they are present and shows up if I hover over the links. Just the slider does not work.

This is angular.json file

```
"styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
"scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

This is app.module.ts

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {NgxPopperModule} from 'ngx-popper';
import { CarouselComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

 imports: [
    NgxPopperModule,
    CarouselComponent,
    ...
  ]
```

I do have all the components installed using npm.

Comment: you mean that when you build the solution, the carousel doesnt slide anymore? anything on the console?

Comment: Yeah, the carousel does not slide. The following is the only console text: 

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.

Comment: I am thinking in the terms of if I did not import the items correctly. Are the typescript import correct?

Comment: just saw it... don't use jQuery... instead go for https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples or https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: @AkberIqbal I couldn't make ng-bootstrap work but ngx-bootstrap worked. Please enter that as the answer. I'll mark that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery... instead go for valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel

relevant **HTML**

```
<carousel>
  <slide>
    <img src="assets/images/nature/1.jpg" alt="first slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <img src="assets/images/nature/2.jpg" alt="second slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <img src="assets/images/nature/3.jpg" alt="third slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

relevant **TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-carousel-basic',
  templateUrl: './basic.html'
})
export class DemoCarouseBasicComponent {}
```

working [sample from ngx-bootstrap site](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbqxx)